# Would a kids dua be accepted for 40 days after eating haraam

Tags: halal-haram

i would like to ask whether there is anyway that my dua could be answered after eating haraam food. I have promised to allah that i will never eat it ever again. I have been eating for around a year at school in 6th grade, secretly. Would my dua ever be accepted as i heard of a hadith saying dua wont be accepted for 40 days if **a morsel**is eaten. May allah reward the answerer of this question jannatul firdows.

Answer (score 1):

Aslamualikum, I cannot tell you certainly if Allah is going to hear your dua or not, just like Allah said: { إن الله يسمع من يشاء } meaning Allah hears from who he wants. If you have not reached puberty yet, Allah will not give you sins. Even if you have sinned, ask Allah for forgiveness, and due can be heard, as we know he has many names and along them are : The most merciful, the all forgiving, the all loving and the all hearing.

Comment: Thanks, but could i also ask whether allah will forgjve me through dua if my dua is not accepted?

Comment: Of course you can ask Allah to forgive you

Comment: Jazakallahu cairan!!!